# Angular Material Ripple appears on top of object content or text

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I have created a sample div with text in it, as in

```
<div class="mydiv"  matRipple matRippleColor="rgba(255,255,0,.5)">
  Click Me!
</div>
```

It works as expected, except the yellow appears OVER the "Click Me" text, which looks wrong.  Am I missing something here?

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ripple

Comment: That's the expected behavior. The amount the text color changes is relative to the alpha. Try dropping alpha to 0.2 or so to make the text color change less dramatic. Check out the official example and type in a color to see it is the expected behavior: https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/examples

Comment: as @Z. Bagley says, it's the normal behavior but there is a hack to do that. (See my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inspect the element (I have the code from this [example](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/examples)), you can notice than the color div is created after the text. So **NO, you can't achieve what you want properly**.

```
<div _ngcontent-c21="" class="example-ripple-container mat-elevation-z4 mat-ripple mat-ripple-unbounded" matripple="">
   Click me
   <div class="mat-ripple-element" style="left: -107.606px; top: -161.106px; height: 511.211px; width: 511.211px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5); transition-duration: 400ms; transform: scale(1); opacity: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

**BUT there is a hack to do that**:

```
.mat-ripple-element{
  z-index:-1 !important;
}
.mat-ripple{
  z-index:50; // 50 for example
}
```